# Base URL in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a React APP. I found below CSS link in Code.

`<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

But I am getting below CSS link in Source Code of browser.

`http://localhost:8080/sam/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`

**How can I remove `sam` from the link ?**

How to set Base URL in React ?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is something that is found in the  section of an HTML file and not in React code. Your question should be in a different section of stackoverflow.

However to try and answer your question:
There are various files in your project, some have an extension .html, some have an extension .js and you have a .css file as well. One of the files that ends in .html contains the line:

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

For example it could be that a file index.html contains that line in the   section of the file.

I'm guessing that that file is probably in a folder /sam. Your css is probably in a different folder

```
Project
 |
index.html
 |
 --SAM\
 |   |
 |    afile.html (contains the link to the css file)
 |
--VENDOR\
 |   |
 |   --BOOTSTRAP\
 |   |    |
 |   |    --CSS\
 |   |       |
 |   |       bootstrap.css
```

Assuming that the file folder layout is as above then you would need to change the line in the afile.html to

```
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

With this change you're accessing the parent folder using "../" and then going from that parent folder to the folder where your css is. All of this is assuming that folders are laid out in the way described.

Comment: Thanks @jaesle. Sorry, I couldn't understand your words.

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the base url in Html head. Like below..

```
<head>
   <base href="/" >
</head>
```

or you can use relative or absolute paths for importing your assests/styles/scripts.
eg:

```
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Note: The paths above might be wrong as I dont know your folder structure. change the path accordingly

Comment: Thanks @vineeth pappu. How can I remove `sam` from the link ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be present in package.json of your project that is assigning sam as the home url, search the sam keyword in your whole project. You might have set up sam as the homeurl in some area of your project.